# Definition of Polynomial Ring over a field generated by indeterminates.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

"Suppose $K$ is a field and $\sum$ represents the set of all irreducible monic polynomials in $K[x]$. Let A be the polynomial ring over $K$ generated by indeterminates $x_f$, one for each $f\in \sum$."

I don't quite understand what A is supposed to be. Is it supposed to be $K[x_f|f\in \sum]$ i.e the polynomial ring of infinite indeterminates?

Can someone please explain.

PS: The statement is form Atiyah and Macdonald Chap 1 Q.13.

Comment: $A$ is supposed to be the polynomial ring in the named variables $x_f$. So yes, if we have infinitely many $f$.

Comment: Thanks. Also if you don't mind, could you also help me out with the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3694132/clarification-on-a-solution-for-atiyah-macdonald-chapter-1-q-3